# Elemental selection sort functions in R

Tags: r

A simple selection sort functions in R. Just for practice.

Given the choice of algorithm and tools I wonder what can most easily be improved about the functions.

NB. I wanted to keep the first function as *elemental* as possible.

```
# Selection sort playing with loops
sels <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    min <- i # this variable keeps track of smallest number in unsorted
             # just some prior, update if confronted with better info
    for (j in (i + 1):n) {
      if (x[j] < x[min]) {
        min <- j # update as we find something smaller
      }
    }
  if (min != i) { # now if we did update prior; swap
      temp   <- x[i]
      x[i]   <- x[min]
      x[min] <- temp
    }
  }
  x
}

# Selection sort in more R'ish-style
selsr <- function(x) {
  # Selection sort a vector
  n <- length(x)
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    j <- i + which.min(x[(i + 1):n])
    if (j != i) {
      temp <- x[i]
      x[i] <- x[j]
      x[j] <- temp
    }
  }
  x
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas, somewhat sorted by order of importance. I hope it helps.

1) There is a problem with your second function, see that

```
> selsr(1:5)
[1] 2 3 4 5 1
```

You should be doing

```
j <- i - 1L + which.min(x[i:n])
```

2) Your choice of `1:(n - 1)` will not properly handle the `n == 0`. Also, it does handle the `n == 1` case properly but it is a bit of luck considering you are looping over `1:0`... The robust alternative to the `:` operator is to use `seq_len` or `seq_along`. Or you could just have a `if (n < 2L) return(x)` near the top of your functions.

3) While on the topic of corner cases, your code assumes that `x` is a numerical vector. You could be checking for that by adding:

```
stopifnot(is.vector(x), is.numeric(x))
```

4) You can achieve the swaping without a temporary variable by doing:

```
x[c(i, j)] <- x[c(j, i)]
```

5) `min` is a questionable variable name, given it is also the name of a base function.

6) This is debatable: I would get rid of the `if (j != i)` condition since it won't hurt doing the swap even if `j == i`. IMO, the simpler code is preferable to the marginal computation time gain.

7) A nit: know the difference between `1` (numeric) and `1L` (integer). Here you are using `1` when you mean to use `1L`, which causes unnecessary conversions from integer to numeric (though the `:` operator brings you back to integers by doing the opposite conversion).

Comment: Fantastic lesson! On 7) Would you convert every instance of `1` to `1L` or just the ones where it is `+/- 1`? On 2) Could I just add `n > 1L`to the `stopifnot`? It seems to work, even if the `stopifnot`is placed above the definition of `n`.

Comment: 7) All of them, but it's really a detail. 2) It is up to you, whether you want the function to return something or error out for these special cases. For inspiration, you could see what `sort(c())` and `sort(1)` do. Finally, I doubt `stopifnot(n > 1L)` will work unless `n` is defined before; maybe it did not error out because you had a`n` defined in your global environment.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake, `n` must have been defined globally.